# How do I check if 'make' is installed on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: ubuntu

How do I check if 'make' is installed on Ubuntu?

I have tried just typing 'make' on the command line but just get the following message:

```
The program 'make' can be found in the following packages:
 * make
 * make-guile
Ask your administrator to install one of them
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install automake`

Comment: I get this message... "
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package automake
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally just trying the command as you've done is a good enough test to see whether the command is properly installed and is locatable via your PATH.  The message implies it is not installed.

All else being equal, you should therefore just go follow the hint and install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

However, if you're not the system administrator, and/or you want to make completely sure it's not perhaps installed but just inaccessible due to (perhaps) a misconfigured PATH (for example), then you can do a system wide search for it.  Again there are several ways to do this.  Here's one:

```
find / -iname "make" 2>/dev/null
```

What this does is search the entire system (from the root folder /) for a file named "make" on a case insensitive basis (the "i" in iname indicates case insensitivity), and all errors are redirected to "/dev/null" -- this basically ignores them.  The reason this is done is because find will get access denied errors on multiple folders which we don't care about (such as under /proc/*). Nevertheless we want it to search everywhere it can.

Doing this will list all locations you have access to with files which might be make.  But as mentioned before, normally make on ubuntu *should* however be installed (as usual) under /usr/bin, e.g. as /usr/bin/make.

If you do locate a copy of make and want to go run it, then you can either type the full path to the command to execute it or "ch" to the containing folder first, and then run with:

```
./make <fill in command line arguments, e.g.--help>
```

Obviously the proper fix however in this situation would be to go add the location of make to your environment PATH.  I'll leave that as an excercise to the reader. :)

Comment: Problem is that I need npm to be able to access it as I am getting "error: not found: make" when i try and install somethign via npm - how do I acheive this?

Comment: npm should find it just the same as anything else if it's properly installed.  Have you tried the apt-get install line yet?

Comment: Yes, I get this message: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package make is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate

Comment: OK.  This is getting a little off topic.  That means your apt-get doesn't know where to get make from.  Please see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean).   I would try "sudo apt-get update" to update apt-get's package cache, and then retry the "apt-get install" command.  If it still doesn't find make, then I'd review my package sources as I'd guess there may be problems in apt-get's list of package sources. (Has this machine been upgraded?)

Comment: Perhaps try: "sudo apt-get install build-essential"
I think this package (if I remember correctly) will pull in make and bunch of other build tools.

Comment: Yup, tried 'sudo apt-get update' - same issue. When i ran the apt-get update command, I got a lot of 'Failed to fetch... 404 Not found ...' messages ! The machine has not been upgraded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96395/discussion-between-joe-privett-and-w-prins).